# UITextView stretches horizontally but not vertically inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

My task is very simple - just display vertically scrolling text inside custom UIView.
I have an UIScrollView with some container with one UITextView in it. Container is needed to add more items later. I use IB(xib file) to add autolayout constraints like shown below:

[image: Screenshot]

But everything I see is:

[image: Simulator]

And it's scrolling horizontally :-(

I've tried setting contentSize of UIScrollView:

- At initWithCoder, didMoveToSuperview, willMoveToSuperview = no effect
- At custom method, called from main viewcontroller = no scrolling at all, and I see the same picture.

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Text View's and Container View's intristic size are set to "placeholder". I understand that I should limit width of ContainerView, but it should work with all screen sizes and orientations, so setting width in code, IMO, worse than setting constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! I've found the solution!

If someone facing the same problem:

You should add left and right constraints not to UIScrollView, but to superview of UIScrollView (to super-super-view).

Unfortunately, this cannot be done in IB, but you can do it within code:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem:self.containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
    multiplier:1.0 constant:-30]];
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem:self.containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
    multiplier:1.0 constant:30]];
```

Where `self.containerView` is view inside UIScrolllView and `self.view` is view outside UIScrollView

So:

You set **vertical** constraints to **UIScrollView** and **horizontal** constraints to **top-level view**.